# Need table name for ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, spring-data-jpa

While starting up my application i see ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.
This app uses multiple data sources.
I want to know what table the hibernate is trying to query.
Basically i want to know the table name for which i see this error

Answer (score 0):

Check table name and schema on Models

```
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE", schema = "MY_SCHEMA")
```

Remember table name are case sensitive in ORACLE